# MySQL - Using index with lag column expression

Tags: mysql, indexing, lag

Edit 2022-01-20: Added "show create table" output.

I have a huge table with from measurement data similiar to this

```
timestamp SensorID SensorState Measure1 Measure2 ...
1         1        0           13.3     .4
2         1        1           13.4     .4
3         1        2           13.4     .3
4         1        2           13.4     .4
5         1        3           13.1     .2
6         1        2           13.2     .2
1         2        0           1.34     .5
2         2        2           .4       .6
3         2        1           11.4     .4
4         2        2           11.4     .4
5         2        3           12.1     .4
6         2        3           11.2     .4
```

with timestamp as int, SensorID integer between 1 and 99, SensorState with 0...5 integer, measure columns are float type.

```
CREATE TABLE `MyTable` (
  `SensorState` smallint DEFAULT NULL,
  `SensorID` smallint DEFAULT NULL,
  `Measure1` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `Measure2` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `Measure3` float DEFAULT NULL,  
  `time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `SensID` (`SensorID`,`SensorState`),
  KEY `idxTimeCode` (`timestamp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=75911538 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

This table has a size of about 20 Mio rows and is indexed using timestamp, SensorID and SensorState.

SensorID: 0 ... 99
SensorState: 0 ... 110
timestamp is a simiular to unix timestamp

id is used as primary key and autoincremented.

**Now to my question:** I try to find those entries, where the SensorState changed from any below 2 to 2. like the following result table.

```
timestamp SensorID SensorState Measure1 
3         1        2           13.4
2         2        2           .4 
4         2        2           11.4
```

SO far I used a "lag column approach", which works well but takes ages. With "explain" I've seen, that my indexes aren't used anymore...
Here is my Codesnippet:

```sql
    SELECT * FROM 
( SELECT `timestamp`, SensorID, SensorState, 
lag(SensorState,1) OVER   (PARTITION BY SensorID ORDER BY `timestamp`) as SensorState_pre, 
Measure1
 FROM MyTable) as T 
where SensorState = 2 and SensorState_prev != SensorState and SensorState_prev < 2)
```

as I said, it works, but is horibble slow. If I add a "where SensorID = 1" into the nested SELECT statement, the SensorID Index is used and the query is really fast.

Comment: *it works* ?? I see excess `)`...

Comment: Optimization question must contain: precise server version info, complete CREATE TABLE, and execution plan (EXPLAIN).

Comment: *where SensorState = 2 and SensorState_prev != SensorState and SensorState_prev < 2* Middle condition is obviously excess.

Comment: ***Exactly*** what is indexed?  For example, the order of the columns matters, whether the columns each have separate indexes or composite indexes, etc, etc.

Comment: Oh. yeah the last ")" was wrong.

I indexed (SensorID, SensorState) combined and timestamp seperately

Comment: Please use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` rather than trying to describe the indexes in English.

Comment: Added "show create table" to my question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `and SensorState_prev != SensorState` is redundant.

If the following is unique, then I recommend it:

```
PRIMARY KEY(SensorID, `timestamp`)
```

How often is `SensorState = 2`?  If less than 20% of the time, then also have

```
INDEX(SensorState)
```

Are there only 4 columns in the table?  You can probably get rid of the outer `SELECT` and simply include `measure` in what is left.

For further discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE MyTable`
I hope you are using `TINYINT UNSIGNED` where appropriate.

Comment: Thank you!
You are totally right I should use your suggestion for the primary key. When I created the python workflow to fill up the database I was kind of lazy. So there might be some duplicate entries for (SensorID,`timestamp`). In the order of 10 out of 20 Mio Rows.

Comment: @AndreasSchulze - I think you can do `ALTER TABLE IGNORE ...` when changing all the indexes at once.  That should drop the duplicates.